# Can the Rails CSP middleware support having both a Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header in same response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy, actiondispatch

I'm hoping to implement a Content-Security-Policy in my application and iterate on the policy by adding rules to a Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header so I can maintain the existing security while testing new policies in my production environment.

According to the [W3C CSP2 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#content-security-policy-report-only-header-field), this is an intended use of the Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header. However, when trying to configure Rails to achieve this, it appears you can either have your CSP in `report only` mode or "enforcement" mode:

`Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_report_only = true`

I've tried looking into the Rails source to see if there is a way to achieve this but it *appears* as if the either/or behaviour is intended:

[ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware#Line:40](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b68eea379524b2690117977562fbd195f52a4fc6/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb#L40-46)

```
def call(env)
  ...
  return response if policy_present?(headers)

  if policy = request.content_security_policy
    ...
    headers[header_name(request)] = policy.build(context, nonce, nonce_directives)
  end

  response
end

...

def header_name(request)
  if request.content_security_policy_report_only
    POLICY_REPORT_ONLY
  else
    POLICY
  end
end

def policy_present?(headers)
  headers[POLICY] || headers[POLICY_REPORT_ONLY]
end
```

Is there a way to configure Rails to handle both headers in the same request? Or am I going to have to set my headers manually without using Rails' built-in DSL?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this to work?